# In Svelte, you can use `array = array` to mark the array as needing a refresh in the view?

Tags: view, svelte, dirty-checking

That is, using

```
array = array;
```

to trigger the view to refresh with the current `array`?

For example, the following uses

```
cards = [...cards, {name}];
```

to "add" an entry to the array `cards`, but by assigning `cards` to a new array, and `cards` in the view will be refreshed.

sample on: https://svelte.dev/repl/3ed20e7bac2e4b65944c98485d9217b3?version=3.18.1
(just type in some names and the list below will update).

However, this is O(n²) when entering `n` names, because each time, the creation of a new array is O(n). If (1) the user is expected to enter a few or a dozen name at a time, it is not such a big problem, or (2) the user may type a name for a few seconds up to 20 seconds, then any delay of the UI for 0.2 seconds isn't a big problem when the entry is up to 1000 or 2000 names. (the user probably will be better to add to the server and database just in case of power outage anyways.)

But in case we don't want the O(n²) time, we could also use:

```
    cards.push({name});
    cards = cards;
```

this will trigger a refresh in the view. So Svelte doesn't do "dirty checking"?  Is it true that compared to Angular, Vue, and React, they do dirty checking by actually converting the array to a string and check whether the array has changed?

sample: https://svelte.dev/repl/70cc3b08f6864ef387c691b8f126a7fd?version=3.18.1

Without the line `cards = cards;`, the list won't get updated in the view:

sample: https://svelte.dev/repl/25f41c51798d425e805fb4586a843363?version=3.18.1

So Svelte doesn't do actually dirty checking but use the `cards = something;` as a hint that `cards` has changed, even by `cards = cards`? So can we just use this as a general technique to mark something as dirty if we use `array.push()` so that the program can run faster? Could Svelte actually guess that `cards` has changed by detecting there is a `cards.push()` statement?

**Update: it was found that by adding a key to each list item, `cards = cards` is not needed, and I am wondering why:**

https://svelte.dev/repl/d78158ae54684bf28b8c2e9b527f1915?version=3.18.1

```
<ul>
  {#each cards as card, i (i)}
    <li>{card.name}</li>
  {/each}
</ul>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assigning a variable to itself is a hint to the compiler that the relevant parts of the view need to be updated — [see here for more information](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/updating-arrays-and-objects). It's designed to allow you to work with mutable objects and arrays where necessary for performance, but to nudge you towards using immutable data structures since that will generally result in fewer bugs.

Detecting things like `array.push(...)` isn't really practical — it's much better to have a single, clear way of telling the compiler 'this has changed', and the assignment operator is that way.

The reason it works with the keyed each block but not the unkeyed one is actually due to a bug — I've raised an issue: https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/4373

Answer (score 2):

You can use custom stores to emulate "detecting changes caused by `push()` method".

See this REPL by Rich Harris
https://svelte.dev/repl/2699eb0fe7dd4621b3e585aec1a30d01?version=3.17.3

Comment: I found that by adding a key to each list item, `cards = cards` is not needed (at the end of the question). I am trying to find out why